# Keyboard aware scroll view scrolling to unfocused textinput when keyboard dismissed React native

Tags: ios, react-native, keyboard, scrollview

i'm using `react-native-keyboard-aware-scroll-view` for form, it is working but getting one issue..

- scroll down to the last input and entered the text
- scroll up to the top of the screen and clicked on dropdown

**Actual Behavior**

- keyboard dismissed and it is scrolling to last unfocused text input box
- it happens only when clicked on out of the text input box or any input like dropdown
  or check button

**Expected Behavior**

- need to dissmiss keyboard and not scroll to last unfocused text input

This is my code

```
       <KeyboardAwareScrollView
            extraScrollHeight={120}
            contentContainerStyle={{flexGrow:1}}
            keyboardShouldPersistTaps={'handled'}
            keyboardOpeningTime={0}
            bounces={false}
            bouncesZoom={false}
            enableResetScrollToCoords={true}
            alwaysBounceVertical={false}
            contentInsetAdjustmentBehavior="automatic"
          >
```

packages

```
react-native:0.64
react-native-keyboard-aware-scroll-view: "^0.9.4"
```

Answer (score 0):

keyboardDismissMode='on-drag'
enableResetScrollToCoords={false}

Answer (score 0):

This workaround solved it for me `keyboardOpeningTime={Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER}`
[Source](https://github.com/APSL/react-native-keyboard-aware-scroll-view/issues/418#issuecomment-617474009)